# How can I access Request object in PostMan

Tags: javascript, request, postman

As title, How can I access Request object in PostMan ?
Is it possible to create a testcase like this

```js
tests["Response content restaurant Id : ", req.body.restaurantId] = responseBody.has(req.body.restaurantId);
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

After doing some research in [Postman Sandbox](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/jetpacks_sandbox)

I finally found the answer for myself.

```
var reqBody = JSON.parse(request.data);
var resBody = JSON.parse(responseBody)
tests["Data"] = reqBody.restaurantId === resBody.restaurantId;
```

Comment: var reqBody = request.data; works for me - with JSON.parse() I got an error

Comment: It depends on whether you're using the form-data or the raw JSON body to make the request @o.z. In case you never figured it out (I realize it has been some time).

Answer (score 23):

If you are doing it from a test script this is the syntax:

```
pm.test("Update env", function () {
    var req = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);
    pm.environment.set("restaurantId", req.restaurantId);

    var resp = pm.response.json();
    pm.environment.set("restaurantId", resp.restaurantId);
});
```

Comment: JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw); worked for me with postman v7.35

Answer (score 5):

```
//this works for form-data:
var reqBody = request.data;
//this works for raw:
var reqBody = JSON.parse(request.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

for application/json request body, you would use the answer provided by Trung. However, for the form data, you need to simply access the body using  request.data and then you can get your variables directly, like  request.data.email or  request.data.password

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in latest Postman version (Thanks to [tom redfern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569662/tom-redfern) comment) ->

```
JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I was using the body as a template, using `JSON.parse` directly on `pm.request.body.raw`, wasn't working for me.

Using `pm.variables.replaceIn()` to resolve `pm.request.body.raw` did.

```
const body = JSON.parse( pm.variables.replaceIn(pm.request.body.raw))
```

Link: https://community.postman.com/t/accessing-request-data-with-filled-body-parameters-in-pre-request-script/9554/4